# Dropbox blocks Windows Explorer - some way to deactivate its Windows Explorer Shell integration?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, dropbox

As soon as **Dropbox** is uploading or downloading files, my Windows Explorer windows become nearly unresponsive, or at least very slow. Unless I deactivate Dropbox's synchronization, I'm constantly getting the blue spinning wheel, and clicking on folders takes forever.

I have a 2011 iMac with 8 CPU cores, 8 GB RAM, Windows 7 Ultimate, a `Windows Experience Index` of `6.9`, and Dropbox runs on an SSD disk. So, pretty much a fast configuration I think.

The problem also appears on my other PC, an older laptop which is of magnitudes slower, but the problem is about the same there.

The Dropbox synch mechanism is fast as always, so it's not an issue with the Dropbox servers.

**Does anybody know the problem? Is there some way to disable the Windows Explorer Shell integration of Dropbox, without disabling Dropbox altogether?**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Windows 7 and fixed it by installing the latest version of DropBox.

I did not first remove the old Dropbox.

Sorry I did not note the version of DropBox before I reinstalled, so I don't know if the new version or simply the reinstall fixed it.

Comment: Seems to be right. It's about 3 weeks since I last noticed Windows Explorer lagging when Dropbox was active. Currently at version 2.4.2. Gonna watch it further..

Comment: p.s. It does look like DropBox upgraded, I just did Ctrl-PrtSc and Dropbox jumped into action asking if I wanted to save the screenshot.  Not seen that before the reinstall.

Comment: Nice feature indeed.

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows Explorer is still lagging while Dropbox is doing its uploads and downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable (or restart) Dropbox shell extension with utilities like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) or [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help.